# how solve long name folders path creation with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, system

this is not really a question because i will answer to it but maybe it will be usefull for someone else: 
i'm on windows and , 
for testing purpose i add to create a high number of folders in folder,
then i use this code ,

createFolder.js:

```
    var fs = require('fs')

var root = './root/'

var start = 0 
var end = 10000





while (start < end)
{

fs.mkdirSync(root+start)
root +=start+'/' 
}
```

this was a huge mistake .

because of this , i was unable to delete the root folder because of the long path name, this was really anoying.

so i try few different method, includely this one :
[How to delete a long path in windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551072/how-to-delete-a-long-path-in-windows)

but i can't figure why it just did not work.

i really was embarassed.

but when i did some test , i figured out than i was able to rename the folder.

as i'm a linux user to i remenber than you can move folder with rename command.

then this was the solution, but you can't did it straight be cause it will be just to long.

so here a litlle snippet that will help you in this case

uid.js:

```
module.exports=function( ){
function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

repair.js:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var uid = require('./uid.js')


var root= __dirname+'\\renamed\\'


var rootLength = root.split('\\')


console.log(root,rootLength.length)
var count = 0 
var pathIt = function(path){

 if(fs.existsSync(path) == true){

var dir = fs.readdirSync(path)

if(dir.length > 0)
{

for(d in dir ){


if(fs.existsSync(path+dir[d]) == true && fs.statSync(path+dir[d]).isDirectory() == true)
{


count++ 
console.log(count)
pathIt(path+dir[d]+'\\')


}else{

    console.log("count %s",count)


    console.log(path)
}


}

}else{


if(path != __dirname){


var way = path.split('\\')
console.log(way.length)
while(way.length != rootLength.length)
{
console.log(way.length)


var joinIt = way.join('\\')
if(fs.existsSync(joinIt) == true)
{fs.renameSync(joinIt,'./root/'+uid())}
    way.pop()
}
console.log(way)

}

}


}

}

pathIt(root)
```

with this code you will simply walk through the last created folder and get the full unc.

then it will simply move all the folder from the last one until the first into another folder root, here you will be able to select them all using ctrl+a in the folder and simply delete it.

i hope this will be helpfull to anyone.